# Organ cloning - possible to make a non-antigenic organ?

Tags: immunology, organs, cloning

From a J. Neil Schulman article on [Organ Cloning](http://jneilschulman.rationalreview.com/2010/01/classic-j-neil-when-clones-are-outlawed-only-outlaws-will-have-clones/):

> Cannibalizing organs from other people also entails the risk of
>   rejection because of incompatibilities, not only for tissue-typing but
>   also for gross anatomical mismatches. Cloning organs [...] has the
>   potential of taking a human being's own genetic material and growing
>   perfect replacement organs which are fully compatible with their
>   genetic makeup.

The reason for using a person's own DNA, is obviously to avoid an allergic reaction to the antigen markers on a strange organ. But in the [blood typing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type), there exist types which *don't* have any trouble-making antigens (such as type O-negative, called a "Universal Donor").

---

Would it be possible to grow an analogous "universal" internal organ, which didn't have any antigens indicating it was a foreign body? (By editing a DNA sample to remove certain expressed proteins, then growing it into an organ.)

---

I realize this is technically a science-fiction question :) But - A: it may not be in the near future, and B: I can rephrase it to remove the SF component:

In the blood-typing system, the AB antigens don't appear necessary for proper functioning of red blood cells - are the antigens on a person's own cells, actually *needed* for any essential functions, or could they be removed, without affecting that person's health?

Comment: Would this perhaps satisfy your criteria? ~  [Could bone marrow transplants be used to prevent tissue rejection of trans-species organs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79881/could-bone-marrow-transplants-be-used-to-prevent-tissue-rejection-of-trans-speci)

Comment: @Pelinore that's interesting, but still doing something differently. More like using drugs to reduce an immune-response. I was asking if the organs could be designed to not _have_ an immune response. The linked method would be specific to one person, whereas no-response organs would be generic, and usable by anyone.

Comment: _"I was asking if the organs could be designed to not have an immune response"_ Yup, while my one asks _if the **patient** could be designed to not have an immune response_ :) I think mine might be easier to achieve (_if it wasn't for those darn kids!_ ~ meaning _ethics committees_ of course).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll contradict the answer posted here (ages ago) and say **no**, it isn't possible. Growing an organ wthout MHC proteins *might* be achievable, but it would be rejected *for not having* MHC1. NK cells instruct all cells without MHC1 to perform apoptosis. In this case, MHC1 antigens are *required* on cells for proper self-identification.

Keeping MHC1-less cells alive could be achieved by

- equipping them with whatever is keeping erythrocytes and thrombocytes (also lacking MHC1) from being destroyed on sight. (A good idea, but see next paragraph)
- disabling their apoptosis mechanism (Cells with disabled apoptosis mechanisms are commonly referred to as cancer, so we might want to *not do* this.)

MHC1 also has a function; it presents "peptide shreddings" from proteosomes to T cells; this way T cells can check if the cell contains internal foreign proteins (sign of a virus infection or cancerous transformation). Thus, removing MHC from the cells would make them very liable to become nearly unstoppable virus factories or tumor cells.

(On a side note, while everyone technically can receive 0 Rh negative blood, group-identical blood is used always, except in rare emergency cases. A and B antigens here, as far as I know, do not have function.)